# Is it possible to create a general ToolBar Manager for an activity?

Tags: java, android

Right, now depending on the SDK version, I either inflate an android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar or android.widget.Toolbar. They have the exact same id by design only for simplicity through this class.The two layouts are designed for 2 different SDK levels. One is for SDK version 8 and the other is for SDK version 21. The one for SDK version 21 contains an android.widget.Toolbar while the one for SDK version 8 contains an android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.

I then use setSupportActionBar or setActionBar as appropriate.

What I wanted was a way to have a class called ToolbarManager inflate the layout depending on the SDK version and use the corresponding code automatically. To do this I wanted a member variable that used the appropriate method.

I wish to avoid Java reflection because it is poor performance.

I want the functions to be oneliners and not use conditionals because that seems inefficient since it is the exact same method. Is it possible to do this in Java?

Comment: why not just use the toolbar from the support library for all API levels >= 8

Comment: I would go with the support library. It's pretty much the same functionality. The official back-port. And while I'm not sure about v7's Toolbar, some support implementations interally set the native View/implementation if the Android version is supported.

Comment: The reason why I am not using the support library exclusively is that I end up with 2 different actionbars depending on if I press the software settings button or the hardware settings button. This is the only reliable way of resolving this issue I have found.